# If condition in dates python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have 2 dates in datetime format, one of them contains date, month and year and the second contains only month and date. ie----> 21 December 2019 and July 3.

Now I want to check if a date contains year or not. My code is as follows:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)

if '%Y' in x:
   print("contains year")
else:
   print("doesn't contain year")
```

But I'm getting an error: TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.datetime' is not iterable

Comment: This is searching for the literal `'%Y'` string the the datetime.  Hence, the error. You can try `x.year`.

Comment: how can I do this condition ?

Comment: If a `datetime` object is not given a year, it falls back to 1900.  So the condition can test `x.year != 1900`.

Comment: If it's a `datetime.datetime` *object*, it definitely has a year.

Answer (score 0):

If x is a datetime, it must be the year. But with the result of 3 December that I assume you actually mean string.

The best tool you can use in this situation is `max`. Get the bigger number in x and check this is a year.

```
x = (2020, 5, 17)
max_record = max(x)
if max_record > 32: #Since we know that the month will be 12 and the day will be 31 at the most, numbers greater than 32 should be considered years.
    print("X have a year.: " + str(max_record))
else:
    print("X don't have year.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Iteration is basically repeating something and in CS usually applies to lists, arrays or other items you can count through. The error is caused by the fact that you are treating a datetime object like a list, and python isn't seeing a repeatable part of the value.

You maintain that you have more than one datetime object, and that one of them is missing the year.  It is hard to see how that is possible, as you are required to supply all three: year, month and day; when you are creating that object.

With that said, we can attack the problem from two directions. First we can assume that everything works that we can check the datetime object for a valid date value. If something might be wrong with the date time object we can convert the object to a string and check the string for the required year info in multiple different ways. The following checks to see if the length is less than a full date time string, if there is a dash in the expected position, and if the date is an unexpected default value.

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime(1900,12,2)

if x.year == 1900:
    print("invalid date")
    
#assuming something might be wrong with the datetime object
#converting it to a string will let you examine the parts:
#string format of object: "1900-12-02 00:00:00"
d = str(x)
if len(d) < 19 or d[4:5] != "-" or d[0:4] == "1900":
    print("invalid date")
```

Comment: Minor correction: “… CS usually applies to lists” should be “applies to *iterables*”, as lists are specific to Python.  Additionally, `datetime` objects should be handled as such; converting to strings for tests is prone to error and/or unexpected outcomes.

Comment: Agreed. The goal was to make the solution understood by a general audience, hence the use of lists, and using strings rather than the methods of the datetime object.

Comment: I understand the motive; however you might agree (as a teacher) the goal should be accuracy and best practice.  :-)

Comment: There is no need to turn the object into a string, which you then try to pick apart again. You can just interrogate the `.year` attribute and any other relevant data on the object directly.

Comment: As a teacher, the goal is understanding not accuracy. :-D -- Assuming that the questioner is encountering issues with datetime then using its methods may not work. I am guessing that the poster is new to python and is teaching themselves by doing a lot of copying and pasting. In that case, another example to just copy and paste wouldn't help them. Also, python examples tend to be little more then strings of dots where objects are calling objects, calling other objects.  This example provides a bit of transparency into what is going on.  But I can expand the example to show both.

Comment: Especially as a teacher, you should not be reducing everything to the lowest common denominator of strings, and teach how to work with objects. Yes, Python code *is* a lot of objects calling other objects. That's how sane code is being written. Working only at the level of strings isn't teaching any good practice, *and* it often makes the code more complicated than it needs to be, if not outright error prone.

Comment: *”assuming something might be wrong with the datetime object …”* — This is part of the point of objects. A properly written object takes care of being internally consistent and conform to certain guarantees about its internal state. You should not assume that “something wrong” is something that can happen with `datetime` objects. You should also look at a `repr` of the object instead of a string; it’s much more informative.

Comment: Agree to disagree. No, everything does not need to be reduce to strings.  In this case, the questioner put forth an example that suggested they were thinking along those lines.  Best practices aren't always the best approach when explaining a topic. If you insist on showing best practice with every example you will chase away 80% of students right out of the gate as best practices are often incomprehensible and boring. You can argue the "correct" way to do things once the student starts asking questions at that level.

Comment: You’re really arguing that `len(d) < 19 or d[4:5] != "-" or d[0:4] == "1900"` is more comprehensible than `x.year == 1900`…?

Comment: If you haven't groked objects yet, the dot notation is completely incomprehensible. This is doubly true about python, which has its origins in flat procedural programming and then has objects glued on top.

Comment: If you don’t get objects yet, then you should get to grips with it fairly quickly if you’re going to write in a multi-paradigm, heavily object-oriented language. It’s virtually impossible to write any productive code in Python without using “the dot”.

Comment: The point that seems to be slipping by you is that people don't grasp programming fully formed on day one. Newbies aren't trying to be productive. They have no concept of OOP. All a new student wants is for their program to work and to understand just enough to try something new. When there is a lecture on details that aren't needed the fun is sucked out and people tune out. Python is a perfect starter. You can dip your toes in and have fun. No paradigm needed. The capabilities are there if the infant developer chooses to to dig deeper, but python doesn't require you do operate at that level.

Comment: But SO isn’t Computer Labs 101, it’s a site for *professional and enthusiast programmers*. No need to artificially dumb it down here.

Comment: Stackoverflow's tag line on their about page is "Empowering the world to develop technology through collective knowledge". Empowerment. Making an explanation clear from multiple perspectives isn't dumbing it down, its empowering.